# What's a foolproof way to iterate over lines of text in Ruby/Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing, text, line, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Ruby 2.3 with Rails 5.  How do I iterate over lines in a block of text when the line separator isn't necessarily "\n"?  I'm discovering that this code

```
text.each_line do |cur_line| 
    puts "#{cur_line.length}"
end
```

prints out three lines if the variable "text" is "1\n2\n3," but will print out one line if the text is "1\r2\r3".  There may be other cases I haven't considered.  I'm looking for a foolproof way to iterate over lines, preferrably something that auto detects the line separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **`split`** instead of **`each_line`**

```
text.split(/[\n\r]+/).each do |cur_line| 
  puts "#{cur_line.length}"
end
```

Split with **`\n`** or **`\r`** both

```
text = "1\n2\n3"
#=> 1
#=> 1
#=> 1

text = "1\r2\r3"
#=> 1
#=> 1
#=> 1

text = "1111\n\r22222\r\n333"
#=> 4
#=> 5
#=> 3
```

Comment: Thanks but isn't tehre also a line ending that's something liek "\r\n"?

Comment: The regex will handle that as well check 3rd example